# cvs to git conversion using cvs2git ; how to resolve error "Multiple definitions of the symbol" elegantly

Tags: git, cvs, cvs2svn, cvs2git

I am using cvs2git version 2.5.0.
I have a old CVS repository that I am attempting to convert to a git repository.
I ran the cvs2git command as below

```
cvs2git --blobfile=git-stage/git-blob.dat --dumpfile=git-stage/git-dump.dat --keep-cvsignore  --retain-conflicting-attic-files --encoding=ascii --encoding=utf8 --encoding=utf16 --fallback-encoding=utf8 cvsroot
```

This run gives me a bunch of errors as follows

```
enter code here
ERROR: Multiple definitions of the symbol 'MYSYM' in 'cvsroot/path/filename1,v': 1.1.1.1 1.1.1
ERROR: Multiple definitions of the symbol 'MYSYM' in 'cvsroot/path/filename1,v': 1.1.1.1 1.1.1
ERROR: Multiple definitions of the symbol 'MYSYM' in 'cvsroot/path/filename1,v': 1.1.1.1 1.1.1
ERROR: Multiple definitions of the symbol 'MYSYM' in 'cvsroot/path/filename1,v': 1.1.1.1 1.1.1
ERROR: Multiple definitions of the symbol 'MYSYM' in 'cvsroot/path/filename2,v': 1.1.1.1 1.1.1
ERROR: Multiple definitions of the symbol 'MYSYM' in 'cvsroot/path/filename3,v': 1.1.1.1 1.1.1
ERROR: Multiple definitions of the symbol 'MYSYM' in 'cvsroot/path/filename4,v': 1.1.1.1 1.1.1
```

I examined the files that throw this error and this is what I see at the begining of file

```
head     1.1;
branch   1.1.1;
access   ;
symbols  MYSYM:1.1.1.1 MYSYM:1.1.1;
locks    ; strict;
comment  @# @; ...
```

One option that I considered was to use --exclude option of cvs2git but I dont want to leave those files out ; there are too many of them - thousands ...
Another possible workaround that I am considering resorting to is to remove one definition - by writing a crawler and sed scripting
However the questions I have are

1. is what is that duplication definition of symbol, why is it there - since it is so widespread it seems like somthing legitimate
2. Why cant cvs2git handle it - I intriduced "-retain-conflicting-attic-files" hoping it can address this problem , but that did not help
3. is there an solution for that

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify - This is not exactly the answer that I am looking for . Its just a workaround that allows me to move ahead with conversion

I am posting here so it unblocks someone who is blocked like I was.

I am still looking for an elegant answer - so this "answer" isnt accepted

For my workaround, I wrote a script that loops through those thousands of cvs files  'cvsroot/path/filenamex,v'  and using sed it removes the duplicate definition

```
for fname in  \
cvsroot/path1/path2/file1,v  \
# thousands of files \
do 
 echo "processing $fname"
    sed -i "s/mysim:1.1.1.1//g" $fname
    sed -i "s/MYSIM:1.1.1.1//g" $fname
done
```

Thus I removed one among the two definitions from CVS files and thereafter cvs2git could progress and complete the job

Comment: That looks like a not unreasonable solution. When I did this (a looong time ago), we had done some "clever" things with CVS that we had to undo (or at least make recognizable to git) and yes, we just went into the ,v files and massaged them. Thankfully there isn't much in the way of checksumming to worry about.